# I installed python 3.5.2 (64 bit) and pip version is 9.0.1 but when i tried to install tensorflow it says it could not find a version why is it :(the

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip

I installed python 3.5.2 (64 bit) and pip version is 9.0.1 but when I tried to install tensorflow it says it could not find a version why is it.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V20GL.png)

[installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9DZa.png)

Comment: Max thank you! But i tried these things. They did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python version seems OK. I have installed TensorFlow on Windows 7 via Anaconda. You should install [anaconda](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.exe) for Python 3.6 version (64-bit).

To check anaconda installation is OK

```
conda --version
```

This command would return something like "conda 4.3.21". If you display conda version, then continue to create tensorflow with the following command.

conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5

Then, you need to activate tensorflow environment

```
activate tensorflow
```

And finally, you should run the following command

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

This [video](https://youtu.be/xY8NAxD37mc) might help you while installation.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I ill try to install via anaconda... but previously I thought to install on native pip( without anaconda) unfortunately It did not work... Okay now ill try with this.

Comment: Would you inform us about the progress?

Comment: It worked thank you very much for your support johncasey!

Answer (score 1):

[Windows install docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
# only CPU version
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```